# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is a brief description of what I am doing.

The application has the form elements in JSP which redirects to the Controller class after pressing submit. The controller calls the service layer which in turn calls DAO and finally adds the records to the data base. The issue I am having is that in the Controller class, I can receive the request parameters (POST) but the thing is that there is an issue while calling the `addStudent()` of the service layer. The issue is with the Null Pointer Exception on object. Could you guys review the code and provide me suggestions?

Here is the full Stacktrace, throwing errors with pointing the object, i.s `nullPointerException`.

```
INFO: Server startup in 4385 ms
Apr 28, 2014 11:45:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
            SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springDispatcher] in context with path [/StudentManagementSystem] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
            java.lang.NullPointerException
           at com.vastika.controllers.SpringController.addStudent(SpringController.java:42)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here are the codes

**SpringController class**

```
    package com.vastika.controllers;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

    import com.vastika.student.model.StudentModel;
    import com.vastika.student.services.StudentServiceImpl;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/students/*")
    public class SpringController {


        private StudentServiceImpl studentService;

        public void setStudentService(StudentServiceImpl studentService) {
            this.studentService = studentService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/students/addstud", method = RequestMethod.POST)


        public String addStudent(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
                @RequestParam(value = "age") String age,
                @RequestParam(value = "address") String address,
                @RequestParam(value = "email") String email) {

            StudentModel student = new StudentModel();

            student.setName(name);
            student.setAge(age);
            student.setAddress(address);
            student.setEmail(email);        

            if (studentService.addStudentService(student)) {
                return "Student is added to the database";
            }
            return "Student is not added to the database";

        }



    }
```

**StudentServiceImpl Class**

```
    package com.vastika.student.services;

    import java.util.List;

    import com.vastika.student.dao.StudentDaoImpl;
    import com.vastika.student.model.StudentModel;

    public class StudentServiceImpl implements IStudentService {


        private StudentDaoImpl studentDao;

        public void setStudentDao(StudentDaoImpl studentDao) {
            this.studentDao = studentDao;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addStudentService(StudentModel student) {
            if(studentDao.addStudentDao(student)){
                return true;            
            }       
            return false;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean delStudentService(int id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean updateStudentService(StudentModel student) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getStudentByIdService(int id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public List<StudentModel> getAllStudentsService() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**Model Class:**

```
    package com.vastika.student.model;

    public class StudentModel {

        private int studentId;
        private String name;
        private String age;
        private String address;
        private String email;

        public int getStudentId() {
            return studentId;
        }
        public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
            this.studentId = studentId;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

    }
```

**spring.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="student" class="com.vastika.student.model.StudentModel"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>


    <bean id="studentService" class="com.vastika.student.services.StudentServiceImpl">
    <property name="studentDao" ref="studentDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="studentDao" class="com.vastika.student.dao.StudentDaoImpl"/>

    <bean id="studentController" class="com.vastika.controllers.SpringController">
    <property name="studentService" ref="studentService"></property>
    </bean> 

    </beans>
```

**springdispatcher-servlet.xml file**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config /> 
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.vastika.controllers" /> 

    <!--   <bean id="studentService" class="com.vastika.student.services.StudentServiceImpl">
    <property name="studentDao" ref="studentDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="studentDao" class="com.vastika.student.dao.StudentDaoImpl"/>

    <bean id="studentModel" class="com.vastika.student.model.StudentModel"/> -->


      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
       </bean>

    </beans>
```

**web.xml file**

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
              version="2.4">

      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/springDispatcher-servlet.xml;classpath:spring.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>


       <servlet>
          <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
          </servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener> 
    <!--    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
         -->

    </web-app>
```

**index.jsp file**

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
              version="2.4">

      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/springDispatcher-servlet.xml;classpath:spring.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>


       <servlet>
          <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
          </servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener> 
    <!--    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
         -->

    </web-app>
```

Comment: give the fullstack trace of your exception

Comment: Which is the line 42 in SpringController?

Comment: Remove studentController bean definition from spring.xml and add @Autowired annotation on setStudentService method in the SpringController.

Comment: You're creating the controller using both namespace and annotation (`<context:component-scan base-package="com.vastika.controllers" />` & `@Controller`) !!!. I think you should use just one way :)

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback. I cleaned up my code and used Annotation which helped the DI of the bean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the **Deployment Descriptor** is **3.1** or not, I suppose you have *2.4 version* as your Deployment Descriptor which is why the Apache Tomcat could not run.
Then check whether **web.xml** is placed under 
**Deployed Resources/WEB-INF/web.xml**